# Set parameter in scope Cake Php 4.*

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-4.x

currently I want to manage my routes with many scopes. However, I want to add a parameter at the begining of my first scope.

for example:
`$routes->scope('{myParameter}/documentation', function($routes){ $routes->get('/start', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'start'], 'docStart'); });`

I get the parameter from the current logged user so i can't write it before in routes.php

I didn't find the solution on the offcial documentation, the resources look close to what I want but my routes aren't RESTful

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether this is possible because it's too early in the request to even have parameters available to pass on.
You might want to consider looking up a stored configuration;
See https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/configuration.html